# ¿Como puedo obtener esta consulta?

Tags: sql, mysqli

Estoy realizando esta consulta

```
$ext_query = "";
if(isset($_GET['status'])){
    $ext_query = " where player_steamid='".$_GET['status']."'";
}
$query5 = $db->query('SELECT pug_playerstats.*, pug_serverstats.pug_index, pug_serverstats.pug_hash, pug_serverstats.pug_in_fecha, pug_serverstats.pug_svname FROM pug_playerstats LEFT JOIN pug_serverstats ON pug_serverstats.pug_index = pug_playerstats.pug_index '.$ext_query.' ORDER BY player_kills DESC LIMIT 0,5') or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($query5));
```

lo que trato de hacer es que de la tabla **pug_playerstats** se enlace estas 2 columnas **player_steamid** y **pug_index**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

porque, busco que de la columna **player_steamid** este obtenga el numero **pug_index** en el que esta asociado para que de la siguiente tabla **pug_serverstats**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pueda verificar ese **pug_index** y obtener información de ese **player_steamid** en particular

Comment: Si tu problema es el query, seria mejor que la pregunta estuviera taggeada con la base de datos, y que mostraras las tablas, los datos que tenes y los datos a los que queres llegar... asi, yo por lo menos no entiendo nada...

Comment: Modifique el post, espero me puedas entender a lo que trato de llegar

Comment: y que problema tiene tu query?

Comment: No me esta dando los resultados de la consulta **pug_serverstats** cuando quiero llamar alguna columna de esa tabla

Comment: Intento con esta consulta `$query5 = $db->query('SELECT pug_playerstats.*, pug_serverstats.pug_index, pug_serverstats.pug_hash, pug_serverstats.pug_team_win FROM pug_playerstats LEFT JOIN pug_serverstats ON pug_playerstats.player_steamid = pug_playerstats.pug_index = pug_serverstats.pug_index '.$ext_query.' ORDER BY player_kills DESC LIMIT 0,5') or die ("Error en la consulta: ".mysqli_error($query5));` pero a la hora de obtener algunos digamos resultados o columnas de la tabla **pug_serverstats** este en la tabla queda vacio no muestra ningun valor

Comment: Bueno a ver.. eso no es una consulta, es un pedazo de codigo con una consulta embebida.... que es ese limit? que hace esa consulta en la DB, que es donde la deberias probar?

Comment: el LIMIT es para para limitar cuantas consultas por pagina van a salir en este caso la tengo solo en 5 y el $db es la conexion se podria decir a la base de datos **$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUSer, $dbPass, $dbName);**

Comment: en esa embebida consulta como le llamas, lo que trato de realizar es lo que explico con las foto es hacer una conexion con la columna **player_steamid** y **pug_index** que esta en la tabla **pug_playerstats** seria como que al analizar la steamid este verifique su index verdad luego de eso comparar el index con la tabla **pug_serverstats** ya que las 2 tablas estan diseñadas para dar un index igual

Comment: Bueno yo paso, no nos estamos entendiendo.. vos tenes un problema con una consulta, pero en lugar de probar la consulta, pruebas tu programa y decis que la consulta no funciona.. Asi es dificil ayudarte... necesitas probar tu consulta en la base de datos, no en tu programa, para depurar tu consulta...

Comment: Lo estoy probando en mi pagina localhost todo lo estoy probando en pagina, si puedes puedo iniciar el chat para enseñarte mejor

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141790/discussion-between-demiv-and-gbianchi).